# how to Rectify "random" list

Tags: php, wordpress, random

Hi can you help me  to rectify the code please 
I want to rectify random list ,what is wrong in this code

```
<option value="title" <?php if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-sort-by'] ) && 'rand' == $_GET['filter-sort-by'] ) : ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo __( 'rand', 'realia' ); ?></option> 

<option value="published" <?php if ( ! empty( $_GET['filter-sort-by'] ) && 'rand' == $_GET['filter-sort-by'] ) : ?>selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>><?php echo __( 'rand', 'realia' ); ?></option>                          

</select> </div><!-- /.filter-sort-by-wrapper -->
```